# How can I detect text language with flutter

Tags: flutter, translation, translate

I need a package that detects and returns the text language. Do you have a flutter package recommendation for this? If you know of any other method besides the packages, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to detect language code; You need to use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/translator). I leave a simple code example below;

```
Translation translation = await translator.translate("Example Text");
lanCode = translation.sourceLanguage.code;
print("Language Code: $lanCode");
```

Comment: this doesnt work becaue it mostly prints "auto"

Answer (score 4):

You can use a solution without packages using RegExp.
Returns 'en' by default or a string representing the detected language code (you can also add country/region subtag).

```
String detectLanguage({required String string}) {

String languageCodes = 'en';

final RegExp persian = RegExp(r'^[\u0600-\u06FF]+');
final RegExp english = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]+');
final RegExp arabic = RegExp(r'^[\u0621-\u064A]+');
final RegExp chinese = RegExp(r'^[\u4E00-\u9FFF]+');
final RegExp japanese = RegExp(r'^[\u3040-\u30FF]+');
final RegExp korean = RegExp(r'^[\uAC00-\uD7AF]+');
final RegExp ukrainian = RegExp(r'^[\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F]+');
final RegExp russian = RegExp(r'^[\u0400-\u04FF]+');
final RegExp italian = RegExp(r'^[\u00C0-\u017F]+');
final RegExp french = RegExp(r'^[\u00C0-\u017F]+');
final RegExp spanish = RegExp(r'[\u00C0-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF\u2C60-\u2C7F\uA720-\uA7FF\u1D00-\u1D7F]+');

if (persian.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'fa';
if (english.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'en';
if (arabic.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'ar';
if (chinese.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'zh';
if (japanese.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'ja';
if (korean.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'ko';
if (russian.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'ru';
if (ukrainian.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'uk';
if (italian.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'it';
if (french.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'fr';
if (spanish.hasMatch(string)) languageCodes = 'es';

return languageCode;
}
```

Comment: do you know where i can find the rest of this list? What do you mean by country? I am trying to separate different han characters by region

Comment: This is not a complete list, these are examples that I used in my practice. Unfortunately, I do not have enough expertise in the Chinese language group to tell you about the Han classification. But I think you should follow this paradigm and use unique features for each dialect to determine its affiliation.

"Country" in my answers means that you can use a more accurate definition of the language that associates it with a particular region. For example, es-ES means Spanish as spoken in Spain, whereas es-419 means Spanish as spoken in Latin America, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it out, unfortunately this does not work well for han characters, it cannot differentiate han in chinese, japanese and some korean  (in case anyone else is reading this). Oh i see what you mean, but it still runs into the han character problems. I'll look around for other solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> You can check string lang like this:

```
  var persian = RegExp(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]');
  var english = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]');
  var arabic = RegExp(r'[\u0750-\u077F]');
  var chinese = RegExp(r'[\u4E00-\u9FFF]');
  var japanese = RegExp(r'[\u3040-\u309F]');
  var korean = RegExp(r'[\uAC00-\uD7AF]');
  
  if (persian.hasMatch(str)) {
    logger.d('persian');
  } else if (english.hasMatch(str)) {
    logger.d('english');
  } else if (arabic.hasMatch(str)) {
    logger.d('arabic');
  } else if (chinese.hasMatch(str)) {
    logger.d('chinese');
  } else if (japanese.hasMatch(str)) {
    logger.d('japanese');
  } else if (korean.hasMatch(str)) {
    logger.d('korean');
  } else {
    logger.d('other');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a small search in pub.dev to check if there is any new lib to do this, but I didn't find it.

However, I recommend you use google API which receives the text and returns the language type.

You can check it in: [google-detecting-language](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language)

A sample from the website you can check:
body **POST**:

```
{
  "q": "Mi comida favorita es una enchilada."
}
```

response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "detections": [
      [
        {
          "confidence": 1,
          "isReliable": false,
          "language": "es"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Another REST API you could use is: https://detectlanguage.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, I can use these APIs :)

Answer (score -1):

In this package https://pub.dev/packages/google_cloud_translation made separate method for requesting language detection to Google Cloud Translate service.

```
_detected = await _translation.detectLang(text: _text);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Huawei ML kit in flutter`
This package is introduced by Huawei itself for flutter developer , So if you want to know how to use it
than
[Visit Here..](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/intermediate-text-recognition-language-detection-and-language-translation-using-huawei-ml-kit-in-fdd2ca413dd8)