# How to find out the Locale of text inside a TextField widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, locale, textfield

When dealing with a UITextField in IOS, you can get the Locale of the text that was entered like this:

```
let localeOfKeyboardAtTimeOfTextEntry = myTextField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage
```

As far as I know, there is no way to do this on Android natively, but (since I'm assuming that the keyboard in Flutter is not native), *is there a way it can be done in Flutter?*

I've looked at the docs for [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) and [TextEdittingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68892411/7706354. not the best solution and your requirement

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing `TextField` in Flutter does not have support for getting the keyboard locale using which the user entered text into the `TextField` instance. If you believe this to be useful, you can open a suggestion to the Flutter team.